# Rotate top view on Z axis to a specific degree

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I am modelling up an airfield for a project I am working on, yesterday I found a setting which allowed me to rotate the view by a specific degree figure around the z axis while viewing from top view ( <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>). I wanted to slightly change this figure, however now I cannot find where it is. I thought it was in the *Quick Access Panel > View*?

The standard rotation of using the Numpad is not detailed enough to get the fine rotation I require

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your view using a "view roll" operation.  This is shift-ctrl-mouse wheel for me, but it may vary for you.

This rolls the view at fixed increments (of 15 degrees, by default.)  You can change the size of those fixed increments in user preferences, navigation->orbit and pan-> rotation angle.

If you'd like to roll your view arbitary amounts, I would recommend adopting the position of a camera (numpad 0 for me) and rotating that camera in its local Z axis.  (You can precede this by snapping camera to current view, ctrl alt numpad 0 for me.)  This will allow you to roll your view any particular value you'd like, just by rotating your camera.  This doesn't have to be the camera with which you intend to render; sometimes cameras are valuable tools to have around in a scene regardless of rendering.